# WebRTC: SDP in Firefox with VP9 encoding

Tags: firefox, webrtc, sdp, vp9

I am not able to connect a call from Firefox to Firefox using VP9, allthough I have tried modifying the SDP in several different ways. I have a site similar to https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/munge-sdp/, where I simply remove the unwanted codec. In Firefox, VP9 is not listed when I initiate the call. I have enabled VP9 on both sender and receiver, by setting `media.mediasource.webm.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`.

Does anybody know how to modify it correctly to get the call to go through, using VP9? I am running Firefox 47.0.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273530/webm-vp9-support-in-firefox says that it's not supported (anymore?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add a boolean preference `media.peerconnection.video.vp9_enabled` that is set to true
-- VP9 for WebRTC is still behind a flag in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Where do I find this preference? I cannot locate it in about:config

Comment: Never mind, i added a boolean value called `media.peerconnection.video.vp9_enabled` and set it to `true`. Thank you!

Comment: clarified the answer ;-)