# WebM/VP9 support in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webm, web-mediarecorder, vp9

As far as I understand, WebM/VP9 has been supported by both Firefox and Chrome for quite a while.

However, on my machine MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp9')
returns `false` in Firefox, but `true` in Chrome.

Software: Firefox 81.0, Chrome 85, MacOS 10.15. MacBook Pro i7 2016. Could it be hardware related?

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Your ideas are appreciated 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All MIME types supported by MediaRecorder in Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739837/all-mime-types-supported-by-mediarecorder-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: This  API suite could definitely use an `enumerateTypes()` method. This business of scattershot calls to `isTypeSupported()` is just a pain in the xxx neck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into Firefox code, I found out that as of today FireFox MediaRecorder does not support WebM/VP9. The source code I looked at is here [MediaRecorder.cpp](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/media/MediaRecorder.cpp)

The implications? 60 second video recorded with MediaRecorder on **Chrome** **5-10Mb (WebM/VP9)**, on **Firefox** **40-50Mb (WebM/VP8)**.